# Using datetime to convert minutes to months

Tags: python, datetime, time, type-conversion

I have a number "436879.0", which is minutes since January 1 at midnight.
 Using the Python datetime module, how would I convert that to months, days, hours?

Answer (score 1):

Using the Python datetime module, you can convert it.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> d = timedelta(minutes=436879.0)
>>> d.days
303
>>> d.seconds
33540
>>> d.microseconds
0
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I get the months?

Comment: Please check this--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226287/how-to-convert-days-into-months-using-datetime-in-python3  to convert days into months..Please accept the answer...

Answer (score 1):

We can extend user1050619's answer a bit by using the timedelta to work out the actual date:

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

d = timedelta(minutes=436879.0)
# Assuming your numbers represent minutes since
# Jan 1 of *this year*
date = datetime(2014, 1, 1) + d
date
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 31, 9, 19)

date.month
Out[5]: 10
```

Comment: @user3756366 To thank people who have helped you out on StackOverflow, upvote all the answers that helped, and tick/accept the one that best solves your problem (there might be a 15 minute wait after asking before you can do that though). Comments are always nice too though.